# Is past perfect with "all night" correct?

Tags: past-tense

Is this question correct?

> "They **had been** watching TV all evening yesterday."

Or do we use it with past continuous?

> "They **were** watching TV all evening yesterday."

My teacher said that the latter is the right answer.

Help, please?

Comment: Your first example would be "unusual" (arguably, "incorrect") in most contexts, because ***yesterday*** strongly implies that the current "narrative reference time" is *now, today*. And we only use Past Perfect when the narrative reference time is *already* in the past (and we want to clearly indicate that something happened *before that reference time)*. So in most contexts you should use *They had been watching TV all evening **the day before**.*

Comment: They had been watching TV all evening yesterday when the cops banged on the door.

Answer (score 1):

"They had been watching TV all evening yesterday."

Or do we use it with past continuous?

"They were watching TV all evening yesterday."

**Both sentences are correct grammatically**. However, grammar is not the  only point your teacher may have been trying to make.

At this level of English language learning,  your teacher probably wants you to understand that the past perfect would only be used in a situation like this:

They had been watching TV all evening yesterday [**when the phone rang** or **when dinner was served**.]

The point is this: **the past perfect is used to describe an action that occurs before another one also in the past**. The easiest way to understand it at this level of English language learning, is to keep in mind the idea of: when something else occurs. Unless another past action (usually in the simple past) is implied or present, there is no reason to use the Past Perfect.

past perfect (had been watching)____past event (when something else occurred____PRESENT.